# How do we get user and group aliases to populate in global directory for Office 365 Exchange?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

We have some users and teams/groups with many aliases in Office365 / Exchange Online.  When we type in the alias, it resolves to the root user/group in outlook.

We'd like to have all the user/group alias show as addressable aliases when composing a message.  Right now, I can type in an alias in the to field, and it addresses it to the user/group root address and does not send it to the actual alias address.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, When the user sends email to someone else, their primary email address is what typically appears in the From field in email apps. They can also have more than one email address associated with their account. These additional addresses are called aliases, and these alias when you typed in 'To' filed will be convert to their primary email address. For more details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/add-another-email-alias-for-a-user?view=o365-worldwide

So your request seems cannot be achieved.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get as well, but it seems to me aliases should be "addable" to the directory.  What's the point of having aliases if they can't be addressed internally, or found in the directory... much less be physically typed in only to be converted?

Comment: A similar thread for your reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/office365-outlook-alias-display/983711d8-32b4-4639-b952-fa4589dcc953 hope it help.